# How to disable specific button in Pmw.ButtonBox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have added a button as:

```
def addButtons(self):
    self.buttonBox = Pmw.ButtonBox(self.dataFrame,
            labelpos = 'nw',
            label_text = '',
            frame_borderwidth = 1,
            frame_relief = 'groove')
    self.buttonBox.pack()
    self.buttonBox.place(relx=.75, rely=.750, anchor=W)

    # Add some buttons to the ButtonBox.
    self.buttonBox.add('Login', command = self.login)

    # Set the default button (the one executed when <Return> is hit).
    self.buttonBox.setdefault('Login')
    self.dataFrame.bind('<Return>', self._processReturnKey)
    self.dataFrame.focus_set()
```

Now, I want to disable login button when user press it. How can i do that? I have found answer for simple button, but this button is in button box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [pmw.ButtonBox documentation](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ButtonBox.html), the `add` method returns a reference to the button that is created. So, just save the reference that it returns and then configure that button like you would any other button.